# How to drop non-unique rows based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
data.frame(name= c("b","d","d","e"),date=as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-02-02","2015-03-02")),s=c("e","b","b","g"),num=c(1,2,2,3))

  name     date   s  num
1    b 2015-01-01 e   1
2    d 2015-01-02 b   2
3    d 2015-02-02 b   2
4    e 2015-03-02 g   3
```

and I want to drop the rows that are not unique so in the case above I want to drop the rows 2 & 3 because they have the same values for `name`, `date`, `s` & `num`.  so the results would be:

```
 name     date   s  num
1    b 2015-01-01 e   1
2    e 2015-03-02 g   3
```

any ideas?

Comment: try `unique` or `distinct` from package `dplyr`. Note that in you example all the dates are different.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly we have to remove all rows seen as duplicated

```
df1[!duplicated(df1) & !duplicated(df1, fromLast = TRUE) ,]
```

Using data:

```
df1  <- 
  data.frame(
    name= c("b","d","d","e"),
    date=as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-01-02","2015-03-02")),
    s=c("e","b","b","g"),
    num=c(1,2,2,3))
```

the result is

```
#   name       date s num
# 1    b 2015-01-01 e   1
# 4    e 2015-03-02 g   3
```